# Setting up Loki on EKS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-eks, grafana-loki

We have encountered an issue with setting up Loki, which has brought to light the need to consider updating our Helm version from **3.5.2 to 3.12.3** or the latest. The current version is causing a syntax parsing error that impedes our progress in setting up loki:

**Error: parse error at (loki/templates/gateway/poddisruptionbudget-gateway.yaml:2): unclosed action**

After investigation from various blogs/forums, it appears that upgrading Helm could resolve this error, This seems to be a common issue with our Helm version, and an upgrade is suggested as a potential fix.

Without updating the helm we want to resolve the issues, kindly help if there is any way out.